# Cannot get an attribute from the root XML node

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XLM file **ProjectPro2019Volume_x64.xml** like this:

```
<Configuration ID="fe23bffc-bde5-41b4-8862-278c5c1b23ce" Host="cm">
    <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="PerpetualVL2019" OfficeMgmtCOM="TRUE" Version="16.0.10397.20021">
        <Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume" PIDKEY="NMMKJ-6RK4F-KMJVX-8D9MJ-6MWKP">
            <Language ID="en-us" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Lync" />
        </Product>
        <Product ID="ProofingTools"></Product>
    </Add>
    <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0" />
    <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="TRUE" />
    <Property Name="DeviceBasedLicensing" Value="0" />
    <Property Name="SCLCacheOverride" Value="0" />
    <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />
    <RemoveMSI />
    <AppSettings>
        <Setup Name="Company" Value="Big Firm" />
        <User Key="software\microsoft\office\16.0\excel\options" Name="defaultformat" Value="51" Type="REG_DWORD" App="excel16" Id="L_SaveExcelfilesas" />
        <User Key="software\microsoft\office\16.0\powerpoint\options" Name="defaultformat" Value="27" Type="REG_DWORD" App="ppt16" Id="L_SavePowerPointfilesas" />
        <User Key="software\microsoft\office\16.0\word\options" Name="defaultformat" Value="" Type="REG_SZ" App="word16" Id="L_SaveWordfilesas" />
    </AppSettings>
    <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
</Configuration>
```

I need to get the ID from the root node Configuration.
I did the following:

```
[xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content -Path .\ProjectPro2019Volume_x64.xml
```

I can do:

```
PS I:\Sources\Applications\Microsoft\OfficeTest> $xmlFile.Configuration.Add.Attributes

#text
-----
64
PerpetualVL2019
TRUE
16.0.10389.20033
```

But I cannot do the following:

```
$xmlFile.Configuration.Attributes
```

This returns nothing. And...

```
PS I:\Sources\Applications\Microsoft\OfficeTest> $xmlFile.Configuration.Attributes.Count
0
```

I don't understand why. Please help.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using PowerShell 7 and the exact XML you posted in your question. `.Configuration.ID`, `.Configuration.Attributes` and `.Configuration.Attributes.Count` all return the expected results. You'll have to be more specific about reproducing things, like the version of PowerShell used. Try doing things from a fresh instance and with `Set-StrictMode -Version 5` to catch things like typos (like the `$xlmFile` you've got above).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the answer. I'm using the Powershell version 5.1.17763.3770. The typo I've mentioned has fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Didn't work for me. `$xmlFile.Configuration | select -Property *` returns `... Attributes      : {} ...` Just left the Attributes property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value of a specific named attribute, use the `GetAttribute` method:

```
$xmlFile.Configuration.GetAttribute('ID')
```